# Simple Injector - Registering plugins dynamically with constructor values from config

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector, .net-4.8, assembly-loading

According to the documentation of Simple Injector one can use the following code to load assemblies dynamically

```
string pluginDirectory =
    Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Plugins");

var pluginAssemblies =
    from file in new DirectoryInfo(pluginDirectory).GetFiles()
    where file.Extension.ToLower() == ".dll"
    select Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file.FullName));

container.Collection.Register<IPlugin>(pluginAssemblies);
```

Let's say each plugin has its properties (name, language, ...) which are specifed in App.Config in the following manner

```
<Plugins>
    <Element name="SamplePlugin" filename="SamplePlugin.dll" language="pl-PL" modeId="1" />
</Plugins>
```

These values are necessary as they are used in constructor of every plugin.

Currently there is a `PluginSettings` class which gets `ConfigurationElements` looping through a `ConfigurationElementCollection` and later on in the main ViewModel there is a loop going through the collection contained in the mentioned settings.

```
public class PluginSettings
{
    readonly Configuration _config = ConfigurationManager
        .OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    public LoaderSection PluginAppearanceConfiguration
    {
        get
        {
            return (LoaderSection)_config.GetSection("pluginSection");
        }
    }

    public PluginsCollection PluginsCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return PluginAppearanceConfiguration.PluginElement;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<PluginElement> PluginElements
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (PluginElement selement in PluginsCollection)
            {
                if (selement != null)
                    yield return selement;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current loading plugins in ViewModel

```
try
{
    var factory = ModuleLoader
        .LoadPluginFactory<PluginFactoryBase>(Path.Combine(pluginsPath, plug.Filename));
    var configAppSettings = new ConfigAppSettings(plug.FactoryId, plug.ModeId, plug.Language);

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
    {
        plugins.Add(new Plugin(plug.Name, factory,
            configSettings, configAppSettings));
    });
}
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
{
    foreach (var item in ex.LoaderExceptions)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item.Message, "Loader exception",
            MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

Each plugin has its own `PluginFactory` defined. Code is a few years old and wasn't written by anyone still present. Further refactoring would include making common Factory in the main application as I don't see reasons for the current state. Plugins are listed in the main app and are initialized (by plugins `PluginFactory`) only when the specific one is selected (clicked) and then displayed.

How to adapt the code to follow good etiquette and process plugins in composition root and inject them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is hard to answer, because it depends on what the ViewModel needs to do with this information.

When it comes to Simple Injector, however, all plugins that you *might* use during the execution of your application need to be registered up front. So, that means that if the ViewModel decides to only use 2 out of 5 defined plugins, you still need to register all 5. (* see note below)

But it likely means you need to do a few things:

1. Load the plugin information from the config
2. Use this plugin information to register the plugins in a collection in the order they are listed
3. Supply the plugin information and an `IEnumerable<IPlugin>` to the ViewModel.
4. Let the ViewModel pick the proper plugin from the collection based on the plugin information and the runtime data given at that time

For instance, if the ViewModel requires the plugin with language `pl-PL`, it needs to find out what the index is of the `pl-PL` plugin from the plugin information and use that index to get that plugin from the `IEnumerable<IPlugin>`, e.g.:

```cs
var info = pluginInformation.First(p => p.Language == "pl-PL");
int index = pluginInformation.IndexOf(info);
IPlugin plugin = plugins.ElementAt(index);
plugin.DoAwesomeStuff();
```

Note that with Simple Injector, a call to `ElementAt` on an injected `IEnumerable<T>` will be an optimized O(1) operation. So even if the collection contains hundreds of plugins, only one plugin will be created at that time.

> *This isn't completely true, because you could load and register plugins just-in-time, but this is an advanced topic which you likely don't need.

Comment: I have added part describing how plugins are handled in the ViewModel. I guess that making the full use of dependency injection and the way of handling it that you proposed, will require deeper refactoring (mentioned PluginFactories) which probably would have to be done at some time anyway. Thanks

Comment: I would, at the very least, extract this logic out of the ViewModel into a class of its own, hidden by an abstraction such as `IPluginFactory`. The VM can than simply use the `IPluginFactory` and the plugin loading behavior is hidden fro the VM. You can than, later on, possibly refactor the plugin factory to something simpler, if required. But at that point the VM will be oblivious to that refactoring.